# Incorrect syntax error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INS_SINHVIEN
    @MASV NVARCHAR(20),
    @HOTEN NVARCHAR(100),
    @NGAYSINH DATETIME,
    @DIACHI NVARCHAR(200),
    @MALOP VARCHAR(20),
    @TENDN NVARCHAR(100),
    @MATKHAU VARBINARY 
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO SINHVIEN (MASV, HOTEN, NGAYSINH, DIACHI, MALOP, TENDN, MATKHAU)
    VALUES(@MASV, @HOTEN, @NGAYSINH, @DIACHI, @MALOP, @TENDN, MD5(@MATKHAU))

END

EXEC SP_INS_SINHVIEN 'SV01', 'NGUYEN VAN A', '1/1/1990', '280 ANDUONG VUONG', 'CNTT-K35', 'NVA', '123456'
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_INS_SINHVIEN, Line 57
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SP_INS_SINHVIEN'

And why md5 error ?

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you writing in?

Comment: @AluanHaddad: This is SQL-Server according to the error message.

Comment: @juergend I see. Someone tried to edit it stating that it was PL/SQL so I figured it would be good to clarify.

Comment: Tell me where I'm wrong? @AluanHaddad

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Is MD5 a function? You need to prefix it with the schema, e.g. 'dbo.MD5'. try that and if it doesn't work, post the text of MD5 in your question above.

Answer (score 1):

You use the wrong quotes.

Use `'` instead of `‘`/`’`

Comment: Yes, but when I run line 1 it's error. Please can you help me !

Answer (score 1):

A stored procedure has to be in its own batch.  If you're entering commands from SQL Server Management Studio, place

```
go
```

On a single line right before and after the stored procedure definition.

Comment: Can you fix it, please ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
EXEC SP_INS_SINHVIEN('SV01', 'NGUYEN VAN A', '1/1/1990', '280 ANDUONG VUONG',  'CNTT-K35', 'NVA', '123456')
```